# Specify Java Localization File

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, directory-structure

I am trying to use the ResourceBundle class to retrieve the locale specific text for my application but am encountering some errors.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.project.MyClass cannot be cast to ResourceBundle

java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name org.project.MyClass, locale en_US
```

The code I'm using to create the ResourceBundle is as follows:

```
static final ResourceBundle i18ln = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.project.MyClass", Locale.getDefault());
```

I have searched for about an hour on how to specify the location of the resource file with no success. My project is setup like the following:

```
project-folder/
    src/
        org/
            project/
                MyClass.java
    test/
    lib/
    res/
        images/
        org/
            project/
                MyClass.properties
```

Is the structure of my project just not compatible with Java ResourceBundle's? Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is MyClass.java some kind of subclass of ResourceBundle? I suspect it isn't, hence the ClassCastException.

If MyClass is not something of type ResourceBundle, then try renaming that MyClass.properties to something else like MyResource.properties, and put your res directory on the classpath in order to find your resource bundle. Make sure that you change the name of your resource when using ResourceBundle.getResource like so:

```
static final ResourceBundle i18ln = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.project.MyResource", Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: The point of keeping the resource properties file the same name as the class is to keep a convention of localization text specific to that class.

Comment: Did you try putting your property file on your classpath as I suggest? That alone should solve your issue.

Comment: Didn't catch that the first time I read your answer. Adding the _res_ folder to the classpath did work! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, and sorry about that bit about changing the property file name. That ClassCastException threw me a bit.

Answer (score 2):

`ResourceBundle` will attempt to instantiate a class called `org.project.MyClass` before it tries to load the properties file. Once upon a time, it was fairly normal for people to compile their code into concrete classes but you don't see it very often any more.

The documentation for resource bundles is described in [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29).

> - First, **it attempts to load a class using the candidate bundle
>     name.** If such a class can be found
>     and loaded using the specified class
>     loader, is assignment compatible with
>     ResourceBundle, is accessible from
>     ResourceBundle, and can be
>     instantiated, getBundle creates a new
>     instance of this class and uses it as
>     the result resource bundle.
> - Otherwise, getBundle attempts to locate a property resource file. It
>     generates a path name from the
>     candidate bundle name by replacing all
>     "." characters with "/" and appending
>     the string ".properties". It attempts
>     to find a "resource" with this name
>     using ClassLoader.getResource. (Note
>     that a "resource" in the sense of
>     getResource has nothing to do with the
>     contents of a resource bundle, it is
>     just a container of data, such as a
>     file.) If it finds a "resource", it
>     attempts to create a new
>     PropertyResourceBundle instance from
>     its contents. If successful, this
>     instance becomes the result resource
>     bundle.
>
> If no result resource bundle has been
>   found, a MissingResourceException is
>   thrown.

By convention, many projects settle on a related package name for properties files. For example, the package `foo.bar` will have an accompanying `foo.bar.nls` package for l10n resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have MyClass.properties in res folder. Copy MyClass.properties into src folder, it should work.

Comment: That is not how I want my project setup. Is that the _only_ way to make ResourceBundle work?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur when the case of the properties file and class do not match.  For example: `MyClass.java` and `mcyclass.properties`.

This seems to be platform-specific; in my situation I was able to build locally on my Mac, but when pushing to a Team City Linux build agent, the build failed with the exception.